# Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences in metric space $(X,d)$ and $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$. Show that $(x_n)$ is convergent iff $(y_n)$ is convergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences in $X$. Let $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Show that $(x_n)$ is convergent iff $(y_n)$ is convergent.

**Attempt:**
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$, there exists $N_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \le \varepsilon/4$ for any $n \ge N_0$.

$(\implies)$
Let $x_n \to x$. We want to show that $y_n \to x$. Since $x_n \to x$, there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon/4$ for any $n \ge n_0$.
Let $N \ge n_0 + N_0$. Then for any $n \ge N$, we have
$$d(y_n,x) \le d(y_n,x_n) + d(x_n,x) = d(x_n,y_n) + d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon.$$
Hence, $y_n \to x$, as desired. Thus, $(y_n)$ is convergent, as desired.

$(\impliedby)$
Let $y_n \to x$. We want to show that $x_n \to x$. Since $y_n \to x$, there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $d(y_n,x) < \varepsilon/4$ for any $n \ge n_0$.
Let $N \ge n_0 + N_0$. Then for any $n \ge N$, we have
$$d(x_n,x) \le d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,x) < \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon.$$
Hence, $x_n \to x$, as desired. Thus, $(x_n)$ is convergent, as desired.

Does this correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I only looked at the first part, which looks okay. I think you can handle the $(\impliedby)$ part by noting the axiom $d(A,B)=d(B,A)$ and the resulting symmetry of the theorem's statement.

Comment: @311411 Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. Can you re-clear it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space and suppose that $x_{n}$ converges to $x$. Although the body of the question has not been explicit, I think we are supposed to prove that $y_{n}$ converges to $x$ as well. Indeed, this is the case according to the squeeze theorem:

\begin{align*}
0\leq d_{X}(y_{n},x) \leq d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n}) + d_{X}(x_{n},x) & \Rightarrow 0\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} d_{X}(y_{n},x) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n}) + \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x_{n},x)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} d_{X}(y_{n},x) = 0
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Similar argument proves the other case.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Very nice explanation, Sir. Thanks for your help. But, I want to ask something. Does my approach above correct?